# Remove special word from end of URLs with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

Google has founded 7500 Not Found 404 Error and I found out that almost all of them happened because of a button with "YourDrible" in href (only this word in url field) and all pages has this button so there are 7 k pages with this url pattern:

http://Some-True-URL/YourDribble

is there any way that I can put in htaccess or somewhere tell that every URL with "/YourDribble" at end should redirect to URL without this word at end?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

In your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/YourDribble$ http://Some-True-URL/$1 [R=301,L]
```